# camera plugin callback blocks other plugin execution in cordova ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

I am designing a phonegap ios app, where captured image from camera are saved in device and image name is saved in sqlite DB. The saved images are then showed in application by fetching image's name.

My case is, the image is captured by camera(using cordova plugin), the captured image is saved in device and image name in sqlite db by using custom plugin. After that the image is shown by fetching it from sqlite db using a function in custom plugin.The process of capturing image, saving it to sqlite DB and show it in application, is a sequence process(execute step by step via callbacks).  The problem is the native function doesn't return callback(success or error) to js. 
I have used the same native function to fetch image in other place, and it is working over there. The function only fails to return callback after capturing image using cordova plugin.

Does cordova camera plugin has such bug?
P.S i am testing in ios 8.1 and my camera plugin is the latest one.

[Link for CDVCamera.m](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m)

```
-(void)ActionSelectQuery:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    @try{
        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;
        NSDictionary *pluginParams = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *query = [pluginParams objectForKey:@"message"];  //"SELECT * FROM Attachments WHERE FileName NOT like '%Images%' AND Type = 'AttachmentFile' AND Id = 2";
        SqliteHelper *sqlitehelper = [[SqliteHelper alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray * returnedArray = [sqlitehelper selectQueryRaw:query];
        if ([returnedArray count] > 0) {
            NSString * jsonValue = @"[";
            int count = [returnedArray count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
                if (i == (count - 1)) {
                    jsonValue = [jsonValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@]", [returnedArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                }else{
                    jsonValue = [jsonValue stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,", [returnedArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:jsonValue];
        }
        else{
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"[]"]; // error callback
        }
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"sqlite exception reason:%@",[exception reason]);
    }
 }
```

selectQueryRaw function:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)selectQueryRaw: (NSString*)selectQuery{
    NSMutableDictionary *storedValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayToReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    @try {
        dbpath = [dbFullPath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &testDb) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(testDb, [selectQuery UTF8String], -1, &selectStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

                while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    NSInteger dataCount =  sqlite3_data_count(selectStatement);
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
                        char *key = "";
                        char *value = "";
                        key = (char *)sqlite3_column_name(selectStatement, i);
                        value = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, i);
                        NSString *testValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", value];
                        if ([testValue isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
                            testValue=@"";
                        }
                        [storedValues setObject:testValue forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", key]];
                    }
                    NSData *dataFromDict = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:storedValues
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:nil];
                    NSString *eachRowValue = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataFromDict encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    [arrayToReturn addObject:eachRowValue];
                }
                return arrayToReturn;
            }
        }else{
            NSLog(@"error");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [exception reason]);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

js Portion:

```
obj.executeSelectQuery(query, function (attachmentObj) {
      //this plugin call doesn't get any callbacks from native
},function(){
    alert("fail");
});
```

plugin call:

```
executeSelectQuery: function(query, successCallback, errorCallback){

   cordova.exec(
                successCallback, // success callback function
                errorCallback, // error callback function
                'TestClass', // mapped to our native class
                'ActionSelectQuery', // with this action name
                [{                  // and this array of custom arguments to create our entry
                 "message": query
                 }]
        );
   }
```

Comment: maybe if you show your code...

Comment: @jcesarmobile i have posted my codes. Please have a look

Comment: this one else{
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"[]"]; // error callback
        } should be else{
            pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"[]"]; // error callback
        }

Comment: post the javascript code too

Comment: js codes are posted..

Comment: debug or put some NSLog inside the ActionSelectQuery to make sure it's working as expected

Comment: i have used UIAlertView inside if-clause from where successful pluginResult is returned. alertView is showed,but the js portion doesn't get any callback